# Choosing photo crashes iOS simulator 16.2

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, imagepicker

```
final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
XFile? _imageFile;
dynamic _pickImageError;

void _pickImageFromGallery() async {
  try {
    final imagePicker = await _picker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
      maxWidth: 300,
      imageQuality: 80,
      maxHeight: 300,
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = imagePicker;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    _pickImageError = e;
    print(_pickImageError);
  }
}
```

```
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>pick image from camera</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Add photo liabrary description</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>pick image from gallery</string>
<key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
<true/>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>


i'm using in pubspec.yaml
```

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
image_picker: ^0.8.6
firebase_auth: ^4.2.1
cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
firebase_storage: ^11.0.8
firebase_core: ^2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [image_picker README](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#ios), you can only select non-HEIC images, when using the iOS Simulator. Accordingly, the easiest way to select a photo is via a physical iOS device.

Comment: same issue , I already selected non-HEIC images , bust same issue